# CodingBat-Excercise: Return true if the given array contains an unlucky 1 in the first 2 or last 2 positions in the array

Tags: java, arrays

> We'll say that a 1 immediately followed by a 3 in an array is an "unlucky" 1. Return true if the given array contains an unlucky 1 in the first 2 or last 2 positions in the array.

The excercise can be found here:

http://codingbat.com/prob/p197308

My own approach works like this:

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {

  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-1; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 3)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

This is true for every array except for [1, 1, 1, 3, 1]. Now I understand why it doesn't work for this array, but why does it work for [2, 1, 3, 4, 5] then? This array doesn't have a 1 followed by a 3 in the first two or last positions either. Am I getting this excercise wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem definition is

> 1 in the first 2 or last 2 positions

```
**[X,X,.......,X,X]**
   \ /         \ /
  first        last
    2           2
positions    positions
```

The `X` marked positions are the locations where **unlucky 1** can be located at.

> [2,**1**,3,.....,4,5]
>
> [X,**X**,.......,X,X]

The **unlucky 1** is in *first two* elements.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you are following the rules. You don't need to iterate over the entire array. You should only test the first two and last two elements.

EDIT :

Reading the exercise again, it seems you should return true even if the 1 followed by 3 are in indices 1 and 2 of the array (since the requirement is that the unlucky 1 is either in the first two or last two positions - the 3 doesn't have to be in the first two positions).

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {   
  if (nums.length > 1) {
    if (nums[0] == 1 && nums[1] == 3)
      return true;
    if (nums[nums.length-2] == 1 && nums[nums.length-1] == 3)
      return true;
  }
  if (nums.length > 2 && nums[1] == 1 && nums[2] == 3) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
if(nums.length<2){
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<2;i++) {
            if(nums[i]==1&&nums[i+1]==3){
                return true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = nums.length-1; i>nums.length-2;i--) {
            if(nums[i-1]==1&&nums[i]==3){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you added some context to explain why this works and why the code of OP does not work. Also,to me it seems more like OP wants an explanation to his code and not (only) a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {
  if(nums.length>1){
if(nums[0]==1 && nums[1]==3) return true;
if(nums[1]==1 && nums[2]==3) return true;
if(nums[nums.length-2]==1 && nums[nums.length-1]==3) return true;


 }
 return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to solve those CodingBat problems with fewer code lines as possible. Let me share my solution for this problems using the ternary operator.

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {
      return nums.length <= 1 ? false : (nums.length == 2 && nums[0] == 1 && nums[1] == 3) ? true 
              : (nums[0] == 1 && nums[1] ==3) ? true : (nums[1] == 1 && nums[2] ==3) 
                      ? true : (nums[nums.length-2] == 1 && nums[nums.length-1] ==3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works fine:-

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {
  int length=nums.length;
  if(nums.length==0||nums.length==1){
    return false;
  }
 else if((nums[0]==1&&nums[1]==3)||(nums[1] ==1 && nums[2] ==3)||(nums[length-1]==3)&&nums[length-2]==1){
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution passes all the tests:

```
public boolean unlucky1(int[] nums) {
  
  if (nums.length == 2 && nums[0] == 1 && nums[1] == 3) {
    return true;
  }
  
  if (nums.length >= 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      if (nums[i] == 1 && nums[i+1] == 3) {
        return true;
      }
      
      if (nums[nums.length - 2] == 1 && nums[nums.length - 1] == 3) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  
  
  return false;
}
```